# Flexbox force on new row

Tags: html, css, flexbox

What would be a way to force a new row for particular group of flex children every time they appear in this structure:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="portrait">portrait</div>
  <div class="portrait">portrait</div>
  <div class="portrait">portrait</div>
  
  <div class="landscape">landscape</div>
  <div class="landscape">landscape</div>
  
  <div class="portrait">portrait</div>
  <div class="portrait">portrait</div>
  <div class="portrait">portrait</div>
  <div class="portrait">portrait</div>
  
  <div class="landscape">landscape</div>
  <div class="landscape">landscape</div>
  <div class="landscape">landscape</div>
  
  <div class="portrait">portrait</div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.portrait {
  flex: 1;
  background: blue;
  height: 300px;
}

.landscape {
  flex: 2;
  background: red;
  height: 150px;
}
```

Desired grid:

```
Portrait Portrait Portrait
Landscape Landscape
Portrait Portrait Portrait Portrait
Landscape Landscape Landscape
Portrait
...array continues
```

I've tried (successfully) a div with break class (flex-basis: 100%;) to be in between (with js splitting the array into inner arrays) but curious if there's a css way? Order of portrait and landscape item will vary.

Comment: No, you would have to set percentage widths.

Comment: Percentage width is fine, it's more about breaking into a new row without any divs in between.

Comment: Again no. CSS cannot detect wrapping,

Comment: I'd just make multiple containers and wrap your rows that way.  Do a container, your 3 portraits, a new container, your two landscapes, etc.

Comment: @Sivak your first suggestion was almost getting it :) But yeah, I guess I'll have to use js to split them into groups

Comment: you would either need a breaking element in between or wrap each group, don't think it can be achieved with css alone

Comment: Would javascript be an option to insert  that line break you need in between classes ?

Answer (score 1):

You can think to insert each elem of specific category inside a flex div, so doing something like this

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.protraits, .landscapes{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.portrait {
  flex: 1;
  background: blue;
  height: 300px;
}

.landscape {
  flex: 2;
  background: red;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

    <div class="protraits">
        <div class="portrait">portrait</div>
        <div class="portrait">portrait</div>
        <div class="portrait">portrait</div>
    </div>
  
  
    <div class="landscapes">
        <div class="landscape">landscape</div>
        <div class="landscape">landscape</div>
    </div>

    <div class="protraits">
        <div class="portrait">portrait</div>
        <div class="portrait">portrait</div>
        <div class="portrait">portrait</div>
    </div>

    <div class="landscapes">
        <div class="landscape">landscape</div>
        <div class="landscape">landscape</div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Flex cannot do this on his own, a possible workaround is via javascript inserting a full width element in between each elements of a different `class` **if you cannot or do not want to modify your HTML**:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  let flexChild = document.querySelectorAll(".container > div");

  for (let i = 0; i < flexChild.length; i++) {
    if (i > 0) {
      let item = flexChild[i].getAttribute("class");
      let prevItem = flexChild[i - 1].getAttribute("class");
      //   console.log(item + " - " + prevItem); // see what it founds
      if (item !== prevItem) {
        let flex = document.querySelector(".container");
        let newLine = document.createElement("hr"); //or any tag that suits your needs
        newLine.setAttribute("class", "brLine"); // add a class to style and eventually hide it
        flex.insertBefore(newLine, flexChild[i]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.portrait {
  flex: 1;/* ?? */
  background: blue;
  height: 20vh;
  /*width:10vh;*/
  margin: 2px;
}

.landscape {
  flex: 2;/* ?? */
  background: red;
  height: 15vh;
  /*width:30vh;*/
  margin: 2px;
}


/* extra css */

.brLine {
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="portrait">portrait</div>
  <div class="portrait">portrait</div>
  <div class="portrait">portrait</div>

  <div class="landscape">landscape</div>
  <div class="landscape">landscape</div>

  <div class="portrait">portrait</div>
  <div class="portrait">portrait</div>
  <div class="portrait">portrait</div>
  <div class="portrait">portrait</div>

  <div class="landscape">landscape</div>
  <div class="landscape">landscape</div>
  <div class="landscape">landscape</div>

  <div class="portrait">portrait</div>
</div>
```

to keep ratio(portrait/landscape) , maybe `flex:x;` rules have to be removed or thought otherwise